# function wont convert array

Tags: php, arrays, function

i would like to convert the received (Model) Product Value into the Original Model Value but my function dont seem to work

now im not sure what im doing wrong

its the function `function identifierToString($DEVICE_PRODUCT){`

```
<?php


$data = file_get_contents('php://input');

$plistBegin   = '<?xml version="1.0"';
$plistEnd   = '</plist>';
$pos1 = strpos($data, $plistBegin);
$pos2 = strpos($data, $plistEnd);
$data2 = substr ($data,$pos1,$pos2-$pos1);
$xml = xml_parser_create();
xml_parse_into_struct($xml, $data2, $vs);
xml_parser_free($xml);

$UDID = "";
$CHALLENGE = "";
$DEVICE_NAME = "";
$DEVICE_PRODUCT = "";
$DEVICE_VERSION = "";
$iterator = 0;

$arrayCleaned = array();
foreach($vs as $v){
if($v['level'] == 3 && $v['type'] == 'complete'){
$arrayCleaned[]= $v;
}
$iterator++;
}

$data = "";
$iterator = 0;

foreach($arrayCleaned as $elem){

$data .= "\n==".$elem['tag']." -> ".$elem['value']."<br/>";

switch ($elem['value']) {

case "CHALLENGE":

$CHALLENGE = $arrayCleaned[$iterator+1]['value'];

break;

case "NAME":

$DEVICE_NAME = $arrayCleaned[$iterator+1]['value'];

break;

case "PRODUCT":

$DEVICE_PRODUCT = $arrayCleaned[$iterator+1]['value'];

break;

case "UDID":

$UDID = $arrayCleaned[$iterator+1]['value'];

break;

case "VERSION":

$DEVICE_VERSION = $arrayCleaned[$iterator+1]['value'];

break;

}
$iterator++;
}

function identifierToString($DEVICE_PRODUCT){
    $models = array(
        "iPhone5,1" => "iPhone 5",           //iPhone 5
        "iPhone5,2" => "iPhone 5",           //iPhone 5
        "iPhone5,3" => "iPhone 5C",          //iPhone 5C
        "iPhone5,4" => "iPhone 5C",          //iPhone 5C
        "iPhone6,1" => "iPhone 5S",          //iPhone 5S
        "iPhone6,2" => "iPhone 5S",          //iPhone 5S
        "iPhone7,2" => "iPhone 6",           //iPhone 6
        "iPhone7,1" => "iPhone 6+",          //iPhone 6+
        "iPhone8,1" => "iPhone 6S",          //iPhone 6S
        "iPhone8,2" => "iPhone 6S+",         //iPhone 6S+
        "iPhone8,4" => "iPhone SE",          //iPhone SE
        "iPhone9,1" => "iPhone 7",           //iPhone 7
        "iPhone9,2" => "iPhone 7+",          //iPhone 7+
        "iPhone9,3" => "iPhone 7",           //iPhone 7
        "iPhone9,4" => "iPhone 7+",          //iPhone 7+

    );

    if(isset($models[$DEVICE_PRODUCT])){
        return $models[$DEVICE_PRODUCT];
    } else {
        return $DEVICE_PRODUCT;
    }

}

$params = "UDID=".$UDID."&CHALLENGE=".$CHALLENGE."&DEVICE_NAME=".$DEVICE_NAME."&DEVICE_PRODUCT=".$DEVICE_PRODUCT."&DEVICE_VERSION=".$DEVICE_VERSION;

header('Location: https://vezuure.me/udid?'.$params);

?>
```

When the Data gets redirected to the next page im still receiving the unconverted value

Comment: What is your original array structure ($arrayCleaned)?

Comment: Don't try parsing XML as a string. Use an XML parser. Why are you messing with the XML before feeding it to a parser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really dont get the point in having a function for this. Tried to clean up some few spaghettis....

```
$arrayCleaned = array();
foreach ($vs as $key => $v) {
    if ($v['level'] == 3 && $v['type'] == 'complete') {
        $arrayCleaned[] = $v;
    }
}

$data = "";
foreach ($arrayCleaned as $key => $elem) {
    $data .= "\n==" . $elem['tag'] . " -> " . $elem['value'] . "<br/>";
    switch ($elem['value']) {
        case "CHALLENGE":
            $CHALLENGE = $arrayCleaned[$key + 1]['value'];
            break;

        case "NAME":
            $DEVICE_NAME = $arrayCleaned[$key + 1]['value'];
            break;

        case "PRODUCT":
            $DEVICE_PRODUCT = $arrayCleaned[$key + 1]['value'];
            break;

        case "UDID":
            $UDID = $arrayCleaned[$key + 1]['value'];
            break;

        case "VERSION":
            $DEVICE_VERSION = $arrayCleaned[$key + 1]['value'];
            break;
    }
}

$models = array(
    "iPhone5,1" => "iPhone 5", //iPhone 5
    "iPhone5,2" => "iPhone 5", //iPhone 5
    "iPhone5,3" => "iPhone 5C", //iPhone 5C
    "iPhone5,4" => "iPhone 5C", //iPhone 5C
    "iPhone6,1" => "iPhone 5S", //iPhone 5S
    "iPhone6,2" => "iPhone 5S", //iPhone 5S
    "iPhone7,2" => "iPhone 6", //iPhone 6
    "iPhone7,1" => "iPhone 6+", //iPhone 6+
    "iPhone8,1" => "iPhone 6S", //iPhone 6S
    "iPhone8,2" => "iPhone 6S+", //iPhone 6S+
    "iPhone8,4" => "iPhone SE", //iPhone SE
    "iPhone9,1" => "iPhone 7", //iPhone 7
    "iPhone9,2" => "iPhone 7+", //iPhone 7+
    "iPhone9,3" => "iPhone 7", //iPhone 7
    "iPhone9,4" => "iPhone 7+", //iPhone 7+
);

$result = (isset($models[$DEVICE_PRODUCT])) ? $models[$DEVICE_PRODUCT] : $models;

$params = "UDID=" . $UDID . "&CHALLENGE=" . $CHALLENGE . "&DEVICE_NAME=" . $DEVICE_NAME . "&DEVICE_PRODUCT=" . $result . "&DEVICE_VERSION=" . $DEVICE_VERSION;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply :) i also tried already to convert the result on the next page but it also doesnt work. tried to insert your code, now it seems to brick something, udid is blank and Model Input says Array

Comment: My Bad. it was a typo. you solved my problem :) i will compare now the code and try to improve my codings :) thanks alot